# text in 3d space - how to carriage return? (openGL, C++, OSX)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

Here is my if statement that detects a bomb threat (just a game I'm making)...

```
if (exodus2_bomb == 1)
{
    float exodus2_theta_math = (exodus2_theta)/10.0*M_PI;
    float exodus2_phi_math = (exodus2_phi)/10.0*2*M_PI;
    r_exodus2_x = radius_exodus_pos * sin(exodus2_theta_math) * cos(exodus2_phi_math);
    r_exodus2_y = radius_exodus_pos * sin(exodus2_theta_math) * sin(exodus2_phi_math);
    r_exodus2_z = radius_exodus_pos * cos(exodus2_theta_math);  

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(r_exodus2_x,r_exodus2_y,r_exodus2_z);
    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);        
    glRasterPos3i(exodus2_x/10,exodus2_y/10,exodus2_z/10);
    string exodus2 = "BOMB!!";
    void * fontexodus2 = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10;
    for (string::iterator i = exodus2.begin(); i != exodus2.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glutBitmapCharacter(fontexodus2, c);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(r_exodus2_x,r_exodus2_y,r_exodus2_z);
    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);        
    glRasterPos3i(exodus2_x/10,exodus2_y/10,exodus2_z/10);
    string exodus2b = "\n THREAT LEVEL 1";
    void * fontexodus2b = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10;
    for (string::iterator i = exodus2b.begin(); i != exodus2b.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glutBitmapCharacter(fontexodus2b, c);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

What I would like to have is a carriage return between "string exodus2" and "string exodus2b". However, it is always on one line. And I don't have the real estate onscreen for that.

Is it possible to add a carriage return somewhere in my string iterator?

Unfortunately, screwing around with "glTranslatef" and "glRasterPos3i" only results in the distance between the two lines of text NOT being consistent as I move the camera.

Comment: Shouldn't shift a translation with negative y coordinate the text down?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Because I can freely move the camera, translating on the 'y' doesn't produce consistent results. The second line of text shifts itself along the 'y' as I tumble the scene.

Comment: If you want to draw text onto the 3d scene, you need to first draw the scene, reset the view matrix, and then draw the text every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render each string separately, and modify the raster position appropriate to reset the string's position.  If you use `glutBitmapHeight`, you can determine how far you need to move the raster position "down" to emulate a new line.

If you want the strings to be positioned in 3D, but then to "act" like they're restricted to the same plane in 2D, you can use the `glBitmap` command to modify the raster position in screen space.

```
int lineHeight   = glutBitmapHeight( font );  // number of pixels between "lines"
int stringLength = glutBitmapLength( font, s1 );  // returns length of string 1 in pixels

glutBitmap( 0, 0, 0, 0, -stringLength, lineHeight, NULL );  // move raster position
glutBitmapString( font, s2 );
```

the fifth and sixth parameters of `glBitmap` control how far the raster position is moved.

Alternatively, if you want these strings to be anchored in a position relative to the window, as compared to a point in your 3D space, check out `glWindowPos`.

By the way, all of these functions are deprecated with OpenGL 3.0, removed in OpenGL 3.1, unless you use a compatibility context in verisons of OpenGL greater than 3.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The issue persists however when I tune the raster position. Because I can tumble the scene in 3d (think Mario Galaxy), the second string will move around and sometimes be on top, beneath, or behind the first string. This occurs as I tumble the camera around.

Comment: You're welcome.  The important point to know is that `glRasterPos*` transforms the raster position by the current model-view transformation.  So, your text is really becoming a 3D object that's moving around (like you mention).  As I mentioned, if what you really want the text to show up in the same place in the window regardless of your camera view, you'll either need to use `glWindowPos`, or draw the text under a different (usually 2D) projection transform (using perhaps glOrtho2D).

Comment: I think I understand. The two lines of text are definitely meant to tumble with the object. Because they are 3d, however, their orientation to one another isn't consistently maintained as the camera transforms. I'll take your advice and employ another (2d) projection transform when drawing them (depth can certainly be ignored in this case). Thank you very much for the direction - that helps a lot. - kropcke

Comment: @kropcke now understanding what you want, I've improved the answer to match.  Best of luck.